# Dataprep: No scheduled destinations set. Create an output to set a destination

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

What does this error mean?

> No scheduled destinations set. Create an output to set a destination.

I am getting this error on dataprep when I attempt to create a run schedule for my jobs. They work perfectly when i simply hit run. But this error appear when I want to have them scheduled

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Dataprep documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Flow-View-Page_57344806) (emphasis mine):

> To add a scheduled execution of the recipes in your flow:
>
> 1. Define the scheduled time and interval of execution at the flow level.
>    See Add Schedule Dialog. After the schedule has been created, you can
>    review, edit, or delete the schedule through the Clock icon.
> 2. Define the **scheduled destinations** for each recipe through its output
>    object. These destinations are targets for the scheduled job. See View for
>    **Outputs** below.

You'll find detailed instructions on how to set these up [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Flow-View-Page_57344806#view-for-outputs).